# Can't detect usb cable on my mobile Application

Tags: android, usb

I have created the android application which tells sets text "mtp" to textview if usb is connected to pc or sets text "charger" to textview if usb is connected to the charger.I used broadcastreceiver for usb cable detection!
When I run the application on the phone and connect usb cable to pc or charger nothing happens it only prints none!Where is the problem?

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        intent = new Intent("check");

        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"))
        {
            intent.putExtra("MTP", true);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"))
        {
            intent.putExtra("isChargerConnected", true);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            intent.putExtra("isCableConnected", false);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private TextView cable;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cable);

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("check"))
                {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("MTP"))
                    {
                        boolean isUSBConnected = bundle.getBoolean("MTP");

                        if(isUSBConnected)
                            cable.setText("MTP");
                    }
                    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("isChargerConnected"))
                    {
                        boolean isChargerConnected = bundle.getBoolean("isChargerConnected");

                        if(isChargerConnected)
                            cable.setText("Charger");
                    }
                    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("isCableConnected"))
                    {
                        boolean isCableConnected = bundle.getBoolean("isCableConnected");

                        if(!isCableConnected)
                            cable.setText("None");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("check");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

        <receiver android:name=".Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
<activity
...
android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
if(intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED))
{
    UsbDevice device  = 
(UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

Comment: I added android:launchMode="singleTask" to MainActivity but still just showing "None"!

Comment: Still same problem!

Comment: You should definitely add insight oh why this is working. _try this_ is rarely a good enough answer.

Answer (score -1):

First, check if the device is charging (USB or AC) using the code below:

```
public boolean isDeviceCharging(){
   return  myBatteryManager.isCharging();
}
```

Then check either USB is connected or an AC Charger by using the code below:

```
public boolean checkUSB(){
    Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
    return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
}

private  boolean checkACCharger()
{
    int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    chargePercentage = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    return  acCharge;
}
```

You can also get the battery charge percentage by using the function below:

```
public  int getBatteryCharge() {
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    return  level;
}
```

**PS: The BatteryManager.isCharging() method can be used for API Level 23 onwards**